# Open and adding a Facebook page from ABUnknownPersonViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I've got this issue, I set up some contact information of a company to be displayed by a ABUnknownPersonViewController. One of the info is the Facebook page, if I click on it on the simulator it opens safari on the correct page. On the device the URL is intercepted by the FB app that doesn't open nothing but my timeline.
I'm aware that the same happens when you try to open an FB page URL inside the app using the method `-openURL:` and I know that this could be easily fixed by using that snippet.

```
NSURL *facebookURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/113810631976867"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:facebookURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facebookURL];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com/pagename"]];
}
```

The fact is that I've tried to intercept the URL by using that app delegate method `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`
 (`handleOpenURL:` is deprecated), but it doesn't seems to be called. 
Is there a way to intercept this opening?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer, using the protocol methods of ABUnknownPresonViewcontroller is possible to intercept some events. I must be honest and say that I still didn't know how to recognize different actions, but in this way it works.

```
- (BOOL)unknownPersonViewController:(ABUnknownPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
    if (property == 46) { //46 seems to be number associated to the property facebook page
        NSURL * facebookURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/PAGE_ID"];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:facebookURL]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facebookURL];
        } else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com/PAGE_NAME"]];
        }
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```